# how to projection/scale image to trapezoid android

Tags: android, image, scale, projection

I have problem with my android application. I want to scale or projection my image from rectangle to trapezoid. My images i received from my camera. I dont know how to scale them. I need some help from you. 
Here is my image to decrible my idea.
[image]

Thank inadvance!

Comment: how did you make that?